# jQuery UI selectmenu doesn't accept widths in percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

If I assign a width in percentage to a select (eg: 100%), jQuery UI computes the equivalent width in pixels and assigns it to the selectmenu widget. However, this causes problems when resizing the screen. Is there a way to fix this bug?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yzzxvbuw/7/)

HTML:

```
<form action="#">

  <fieldset>
    <label for="speed">Select a speed</label>
    <select name="speed" id="speed">
      <option>Slower</option>
      <option>Slow</option>
      <option selected="selected">Medium</option>
      <option>Fast</option>
      <option>Faster</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>

</form>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{font-family:arial}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
}
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#speed" ).selectmenu();
  });
```

Comment: NB: I am also having a related bug (that I wasn't able to replicate in JSFiddle unfortunately): I assign a percentage of 100% to a select and jQuery UI gives a width of 100px instead. I tried putting another percentage such as 88% and the same thing happens (88px).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cprw123d/1/ ? - a bit costly(destroying and recreating the widget) but does what you need, the widget calculates the dimensions and sets the inline width

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the item to verify the jquery UI iD that's assigned. It's often `#[element]-button` for select menus.

Then apply the CSS to that ID. In this case

```
#speed-button {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
```

Seems to fix the issue: **[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/yzzxvbuw/8/)**

You could also target the general jquery UI classes that are created. i just find those to be time consuming to sort out when the ID will do the same thing if you are only dealign with 1 or 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.ui-selectmenu-button{width:100%}
```

JSFiddle:  `https://jsfiddle.net/yzzxvbuw/11/`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to override the jQuery UI style like

```js
$(function() {
  $("#speed").selectmenu();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial
}
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
select {
  width: 100%;
}
#speed + .ui-selectmenu-button {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo">

  <form action="#">

    <fieldset>
      <label for="speed">Select a speed</label>
      <select name="speed" id="speed">
        <option>Slower</option>
        <option>Slow</option>
        <option selected="selected">Medium</option>
        <option>Fast</option>
        <option>Faster</option>
      </select>


    </fieldset>

  </form>

</div>
```